# Preventing Hangul (Korean) words from splitting and breaking onto the next line

Tags: line-breaking

I am working on a document in Korean, using Hangul characters.

It appears that LaTeX freely breaks apart words when it breaks lines naturally.

I want to force LaTeX to ONLY break lines on whitespace, and never split conjoined glyphs.

Consider the following example, where (numbered) lines 2, 6, 9, 18, 19, 22, 27, 28, 29, and 32 all begin with glyphs orphaned from their parent on the previous line.

How do we configure the rules of natural line breaks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{kotex}  
\usepackage{lineno}

\begin{document}
\linenumbers
\Large
    한국, 조선, 또는 코리아는 동아시아에 위치한 지역 또는 헌법상의 국가로, 현대사에서는 한반도의 대한민국과 조선민주주의인민공화국을 이르는 말이다. 한국은 대한민국을, 조선은 조선민주주의인민공화국을 이르는 경우가 잦다. 근현대사에서 한국은 고종이 수립한 대한제국을 일컫는 말이었다. 넓은 의미로 한국은 고조선 이후 한반도에서 설립된 여러 한민족의 국가를 통칭하는 말이다. 한국의 역사를 한국사라고 한다.

    한국인의 뿌리 이루는 종족은 한(韓), 예(濊), 맥(貊)이다. 이들에 의해 고조선, 북부여(扶餘), 진국(辰國, 삼한 성립 이전)과 같은 초기 국가들이 생겨났다. 기원전 15세기 - 기원전 11세기쯤에는 청동기 문화가 들어왔으며 이와 함께 초기 고대 국가들이 생겨났는데 이 중 고조선(古朝鮮)이 가장 강했다.

    왕검성(王儉, 고조선 수도)에서 세워진 단군조선은 청동기 문화를 지녔고 명도전(明刀錢)이라는 화폐를 만드는 등 수준 높은 문화를 자랑하였다. 그러나 기원전 4세기 후반과 기원전 3세기 전반에 연나라와의 전쟁에서 패하여 서쪽의 거점들을 빼앗긴 뒤 중심지를 오늘날의 평양(平壤) 지역으로 옮겨갔다.

    고조선 내 세력들 중 일부는 경주(慶州) 인근 진한 땅으로 이동하여 6개 촌을 이루며 살다가 기원전 57년 사로국을 성립시켜 신라로 발전하였다. 또한 일부는 김해 지역의 변한(弁韓) 땅에 9개의 촌을 형성하여 살다가 1세기경에 구야국에서 가야로 발전하고, 일부세력은 경기도와 전라도 지역의 마한 땅에 정착하였다. 한편 만주 지역에서는 기원전 11세기 무렵에 부여가 형성되었으며, 부여에서 주몽 일파가 졸본 지역으로 남하하여 맥족과 연합 또는 병합하여 고구려를 건국하였다. 주몽 일파와 유리 일파가 졸본 지역으로 이동해 오자 온조와 비류 일파는 남쪽의 마한 지역으로 이동하여 마한 북부 지역의 한강 유역 일대를 중심으로 백제를 건국하게 된다. 또한 북부여에서 고씨 세력에 밀린 해씨 세력 일부가 가섭원 지역으로 이주하여 물길족, 예족, 맥족 등을 병합하여 동부여를 건국하였다.

    고조선 멸망 이후 1세기-3세기 북쪽에는 고구려와 동부여, 남쪽에는 가야 등이 먼저 발전하여 전기 삼국시대를 형성하였고, 4세기-6세기 고구려, 백제, 신라로 대표되는 세 나라는 중앙 집권 체제를 확립시켜 수세기 동안 서로 경쟁하기도 하고 교류하기도 하면서 발전했는데, 이 시기를 전기 삼국 시대라고 부른다. 고구려는 광개토왕과 장수왕때 크게 발전하여 만주와 한반도를 호령하였고, 대흥안령 산맥에도 진출하였으며, 수,당과 맞서 싸우며 민족의 방파제 구실을 하였다.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: sorry I can't read the kotex manual, but this seems to be for pdftex? I would guess that these days you would get better hangul-specific rules with harfbuzz based rendering so xelatex or luahbtex and specifying a suitable font via fontspec. But really this is a comment from a position of zero knowledge, so I may delete it if it proves misleading...

Answer (score 1):

Add to the preamble:

```
\usepackage{dhucs}
\disablehangullinebreak
```

But there will be lots of overfull lines.